# Accessing dynamically named tables using a new object in R

Tags: r

I have some sequentially labeled data frames i.e frame_1 frame_2 e.t.c...  I would like to access them in a sequential manner possibly using a loop

one way that makes sense to me is to assign the name of the data frame I want to access to an object, then pass that object to a function i.e

```
varname<-paste("frame_",1,_sep="")
```

then  call my function

```
function(varname)
```

But R appears to call the function on a string varname, and not the object with the same name as varname.

Is there  way I can do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: `mget(ls(pattern = "frame_\\d+"))` maybe?

Comment: Why are you not storing these data frames in a list?

Comment: @SeñorO I tried that but the extra level of indexation made other tasks harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you can parse a string as an R command using a combination of eval and parse, so for instance :

```
   function( eval( parse(text=paste0("name_",1))) )
```

In a loop:

```
for( i in 1:length(holder)){
  function(eval( parse(text=paste0("frame_",i))) )
}
```

Comment: Just found this question/answer while looking for duplicates of a similar question. `eval(parse())` works for this, but is overkill. `get()` is simpler, but as Senor O said in comments using a list is considered best practice.